# How to organize development of Rails App and multiple Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, bundler, rails-engines

It's hard to formulate the question actually so I just explain the situation.

I'm working on a application that consists of multiple sub applications. The main app just provides an navigation bar and some basic functionality like configuration of users and permissions while the sub applications provide the actual functionalities.

Now this is a Rails 2 application and the sub applications get embedded in frames, it's not really nice design and pretty complex to setup.
Fortunately we have Engines now and that would be the saner solution for this application.

Until now everything lives in subversion and can be updated at once, shared code uses externals. We would like to move to git while we're at restructuring and refactoring.
I've been searching the web the past few days about bundler, git submodules and git subtrees but I haven't found a good description how to properly manage a large project which consists of multiple Engines/Gems when you are developing on all of them the same time.

In particular I would like to be able to:

- use Bundler to manage dependencies
- do not install our own Gems and Engines into the global gem path but relative to the main app, as an git repository
- have our own Gems and Engines setup as git repository (maybe with Bundler's local path override)
- an easy way to fetch all dependencies (bundle install) which pulls the latest version of our own Gems and Engines, if that's not possible then one command to git pull all own Gems and Engines (maybe an rake task?)
- make it easy for new developers to setup the entire development enviroment fast (git clone the app, bundle install dependencies including all own Gems and Engines, locally)
- deploy with Capistrano, easily

What I already thought about:

- including everything into one repository, seems to defeat the purpose of separate Gems/Engines for me, also I think it wouldn't allow us to manage the dependencies of the main app on our Engines via Bundler
- using submodules, I read too many posts about why it's bad, and with our number of developers it's only a matter of time until somebody commits a submodule pointer to a commit that only exists in his local repo
- git subtree utility, seems quite complex to me

So has anybody of you a similar setup and how do you manage it to make updating and committing changes as easy as possible? Where do you put your Engine/Gem code on which the application depends?

**TL;DR** How do manage a large rails project which consists of multiple Engines and Gems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a similar (but probably less complex) case at my company. What we do (as for now) and that could work for you too :

Put your Rails app in its own git repository. The various gems each get their own repository also (while it is possible to do otherwise, the "one gem = one git repository" will make your life easier).

Then in your Rails app Gemfile, you have several options

- Default should be to refer each gem to its git repository (so that bundle will load them from there)
- When working locally on some of the gems and the Rails app, either change the Gemfile to use the local path (http://gembundler.com/v1.2/gemfile.html) or better, by overriding the path locally (see: http://gembundler.com/v1.2/git.html). Be careful that those two options are different : the first one use the path, the second the local git repository (so a new uncommitted change will be visible by the first, not by the second).

For updating all your gems easily, I would create a small .sh script (just to launch the various clone or update operations, and the bundle install so that everything comes out clean), and commit it with the main app. I would also get a "standard folder organization" among the team (ie, that everyone use a base folder of their choice, with under it folders for the Rails app and each gem), to make the procedure easier.

I hope this can help or get you ideas (your question is quite complex and manifold, so I'm not 100 % sure this is what you are looking for).

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is what we are going to do as soon as somebody dares to start the migration to git.

Comment: Instead of creating that "bundle install" script yourself, this gem will do it for you: https://github.com/EPI-USE-Labs/git-bundle

Comment: If you need to extend functionality between the engines/git repo's, you can use the decorator pattern with this gem: https://github.com/EPI-USE-Labs/activesupport-decorators

Answer (score 1):

**How to manage your Gem dependencies?**
Bundler via Gemfile.

**How to manage your Engines?**
Bundler via Gemfile.
Architect your Engines as Gems and provide their git repo location in your Gemfile.  If you want examples, check out how to include the https://github.com/radar/forem gem in your Gemfile.

Also, this helped me learn Rails Engines, http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html.

**Are you coming from Java Land?**
Rails does have a learning curve, but not like the Java mountain cliff drop off.

Comment: I did Java before Ruby yes, but all in all I did more Ruby than Java.I think you over read the part with developing multiple engines at the same time.I'm sorry but your answer doesn't provide anything new to me.